# Why make_heap() is not making minimum heap?

Tags: c++, stl, c++17, heap

I am trying to **make_heap()** a vector of integers with a comparator function for minimum integer ordering, but when I am trying to check front value of the vector *(which should be the **lowest** among the heap values)*, it is not 1. Even after debugging my code, I can't figure out why. Basically, I want to extract lowest integer data for n no. of times from the heap where **n = no. of data in the vector**. Thank you.

The final data of result variable must be {1,2}.

[image: Debug screen shows returned data from my first nums.front() is 2, which should be 1]

This is my code

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

std::vector<int> targetIndices(std::vector<int>& nums, int target) {
        int i = 0, j = nums.size() - 1;
        std::vector<int> result;
        std::make_heap(nums.begin(),nums.end(),std::greater<int>());
        while(nums.size())   {
            std::pop_heap(nums.begin(), nums.end(),std::greater<int>());
            int data = nums.front();
            nums.pop_back();
            if(data > target)   return result;
            if(data == target)   result.push_back(i);
            i++;
        }
        return result;
    }
int main()  {
  std::vector<int> nums = {2,5,2,3,1};
  std::vector<int> result = targetIndices(nums, 2);
  for(int i : result)
  std::cout << i <<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Please [do not upload images of code, data, or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: `when I am trying to check front value of the vector (which should be the lowest among the heap values), it is not 1` - maybe this is because you call `pop_heap` (which "removes" the lowest value) before checking the value?

Comment: @dewaffled pop_heap() does not remove a value. [Docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/pop_heap)

Comment: what do you expect `pop_heap` to do? `Swaps the value in the position first and the value in the position last-1 and makes the subrange [first, last-1) into a heap. This has the effect of removing the first element from the heap defined by the range [first, last).`